# Does a metal evaporate as single atoms or as molecules?

Tags: phase-transition, metals, evaporation, liquid-state

If I had a liquid metal, like Al, and I begin heating it so it evaporates, would the evaporating Al be in the form of atoms or as molecules?

Comment: You can easily answer this for any metal by looking up their gaseous phase parameters.  BTW, solids evaporate too.

Comment: Modeling the gas phase of the Al-N phase diagram in the COST 507 database uses the Al dimer in addition to the monomer (and N, N2, and N3 on the nitrogen side). Generally not needed by most other binary phase diagram thermodynamic assessments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about chemistry.

Comment: Aluminum oxidizes easily with oxygen Al2O3 and I assume that this also happens immediately through contact with the air.

Answer (score 5):

Aluminium does not form molecules. Thus, the basic entities of this liquid are aluminium atoms (again unlike in water), and they will evaporate as atoms.